# React Native vs Native Development and Map Views

Tags: android, ios, mobile, react-native

I have written React and a basic React Native app before and have done a little native iOS and Android. I am looking to build a mobile application that will need to include a Map View. (I think both Apple and Android have their own Map Views in their native libraries.) I really love React for the development speed and the natural UI data flow, especially when combined with Redux, but I do not want to miss out on some of the subtle features each of the native SDKs offers on their own.

1. Will React have a map view that I can use?
2. What types of native views from Apple and Android does React Native lack?
3. Does React Native have a way to compensate for any of these missing views?
4. Experts, what do you recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: For a cross-platform solution, the React [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.31/docs/mapview.html) recommend using Airbnb's [react-native-maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/lib/ios/AirMaps/AIRMapPolygon.h). Judging by the [source code](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/lib/ios/AirMaps/AIRMapPolygon.h) it uses native maps e.g. MapKit for iOS. However, it is NOT maintained so please be aware of that before you commit to using it.